# MySQL keyring_file not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied) on WAMP64 MySQL 5.7.19

Tags: mysql, encryption, wamp

I’m running WAMP64 on Windows 10 (development machine), with MySQL 5.7.19.  I’ve installed the keyring_file plugin.  MySQL starts, but the keyring_file is not found, so the following errors:

> [ERROR] Plugin keyring_file reported: 'File
>   'C:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.19/lib/plugin/keyring_file.dll' not
>   found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)' [ERROR] Plugin keyring_file
>   reported: 'keyring_file initialization failure. Please check if the
>   keyring_file_data points to readable keyring file or keyring file can
>   be created in the specified location. The keyring_file will stay
>   unusable until correct path to the keyring file gets provided'

The file is on the specified path: 
 [image]

My.ini includes:
[image]

The variables loads:
[image]

The plugin appears to load:
[image]

And the mysql service has Local System permission:
[image]

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing the plugins, granting broader permissions on the keyring.dll file, and of course I have re-started the MySQL service after each test.

So my question is why am I getting Errcode 13, permission denied?  What am I missing here?  Thanks.

Comment: Something not running as `root`?

Comment: No, see the accepted answer and comment.  You have to create a keyring file, not point to the working file (dll).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are specifing the `.dll` file for the `keyring_file_data` variable, not the location of a file to use for the keyring. It should be something like:

```
keyring_file_data=C:/some/path/to/keyring
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keyring-file-plugin.html

Comment: Thanks.  But it's worth noting (mysql docs don't) that the variable is a filename, not a path, and you have to create an empty file there.  Once I did that, it's working.